# How to securely email something to myself from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, security, email

I'd like to implement a feature in my app where the user can enter some data, and upon pressing a submit button the app then logs into an email account and sends me an email (so that I can then view the data the user entered). I don't want to just store my password in plain text in the app, so are there any more secure ways to accomplish this?

I understand that usually it's best to just build a custom backend and have the app make a post request, but that won't be possible here.

Comment: What you want is a public-private key system, such as GnuPG, so that you can encrypt using your public key. Unfortunately there's nothing like that built-into iOS. There are public-key encryption tools (see `SecKeyEncrypt`), but they're not trivial to use.

Comment: Why can't the app post a request to your server?  If it can't make a web request why would it be able to log into an email server?

Comment: @Paulw11 because I don't have a server.

Comment: Ok.  I thought it might be a networking restriction or something.  In that case I would look at [MailGun](https://mailgun.com).  They have an API that makes it simple to send emails.  You need to use an API key for authentication and there is a risk that it could be extracted from your app if you include it in your app.  You could set up a Google App Engine or AWS function to receive a request from your app and forward it on using Mailgun.  That way the destination email address and the API key are safely stored on the server code.  Depending on volume, MailGun and the server could be free.

Comment: If you are using Gmail, you can always create a new email-id saying support_your_app_name@gmail.com and then link it to your primary email.